# Code for sequences of digits 10^8 possibilities

Tags: python

How can I make python code such that it prints all sequences of digits 8 digits long? (for 10^8 possibilities)
An example is 56789504.
I tried something with for loops but that didn't work:

```
def my_range(10000000, 99999999, 1):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += step

for x in my_range(1, 10, 0.5):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Iterate through `10^8` through `10^9-1`?

Comment: "I tried something with for loops but that didn't work." - what did you try? `range(10e8, 10e9)` will generate them all...

Comment: Why don't you post the errors you got?

Answer (score 1):

`range(n,m)` gives you integers `>=n` and `<m`, so this would theoretically give you what you want:

```
print(list(range(10_000_000,100_000_000)))
```

however, actually listing out each and every number wont work, because there is a HUGE amount of numbers. For reference, running this:

```
print(list(range(10_000_000,11_000_000)))
```

took my computer about a minute to run. it's unlikely that your computer is actually capable of printing out each and every number in (10_000_000,100_000_000)

one way to help with this is by indexing. you can set a range like this:

```
gen = range(10_000_000,100_000_000)
```

which, when you index, you can pull out specific values:

```
print(gen[345])
```

results in `10_000_345`. You can use a range just like you would use a `list`

Comment: `100000000` is extremely hard to read either use `100_000_000` or just `10e8`.

Comment: A range is not a generator but a proper sequence with a length and everything.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, you're right, my b, fixed it and read up on why they aren't generators, pretty cool

Comment: @Dan nice name. Also, I wanted to make sure the code was easily run able, and didn't want to confuse the op with concepts like casting and stuff. Everything is a tradeoff, totally see where you're coming from

Comment: There is no casting - both `100_000_000` and `10e8` are int literals in python. It wouldn't change a thing about your code, just the readability :)

Comment: @Dan, weird, I tried to run underscores on my local machine but I got an invalid syntax error, which is why I didn't change the formatting. But yeah, it definitely is a thing. You learn something new every day

Comment: What version of Python are you on?

Comment: @Dan printing out the python version and version info, I get this: ***Python version***
3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
***Version info***.
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: Aha, it was added only in [3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-515-underscores-in-numeric-literals). Is there a reason you're on such an old version? No f-strings :(

Comment: Haha, go figure; I've been working in the same environment for a while for work. Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Try the segment below:

```
for i in range (10):
    for j in range (10):
        for k in range (10):
            for l in range (10):
                for m in range (10):
                    for n in range (10):
                        for o in range (10):
                            for p in range (10):
                                print(i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p)
```

This will give you answers including ones with zeros in the front (e.g. 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1).

If you don't want the space between the output (i.e. 00000001), try this:

```
for i in range (10):
    for j in range (10):
        for k in range (10):
            for l in range (10):
                for m in range (10):
                    for n in range (10):
                        for o in range (10):
                            for p in range (10):
                                print(i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, sep='')
```

Given you're not looking for that, you should be able to do:

```
for i in range (99999999):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I am a beginner, sorry for my ignorance in this.

Comment: @WWesEEE No worries, we all start somewhere. Best of luck!

Comment: This is a really crappy way of doing it (except the last one)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know it's not really great, but I wasn't entirely sure what they wanted. The first two ones are mainly just to get the zeros in the front of the number in case they needed it to output strings all of a specific character length. The third one does not output strings and they are not of a specific character length. I saw a need to display all three options due to the ambiguity of the question

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well, maybe except the first one. I really, really don't like the output format, but who knows what they'll need

Comment: @lime. `f'{blah:09d}'` will display the zeros